# How to extend the QTreeView in a Grid layout?

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4

I am trying to create a Dialog with a tree view and a web view. Both the views are set as grid layout. The issue is that the treeview cannot be expended once the application is launched. It changes the size with the change in the whole dialog box but when I specifically try to expand the treeview without changing the dialog window size, it doesn't provide me that option. I am using PyQt4 to design the Dialog. Here is the code:

```
class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(511, 393)
        sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(Dialog.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        Dialog.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(Dialog)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
        self.listView = QtGui.QListView(Dialog)
        self.listView.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("listView"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.listView)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_2"))
        self.webView = QtWebKit.QWebView(Dialog)
        self.webView.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl(_fromUtf8("about:blank")))
        self.webView.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("webView"))
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.webView)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        pass

from PyQt4 import QtWebKit

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Once a widget is inside a layout, generally the layout decides how big the widget will be. 
You can influence this by setting the size policy or stretch factors on the widget. See: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/layout.html

If you want to force the widget to have a specific size, use QWidget.setFixedSize.